# Remove objects having same ID and its Status

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I have a array list results which is having bellow objects.

```
Results[Event[ID=ace-453, status=Inprogress , startTime= "2020-04-20 07:05:28"], 
        Event[ID=ace-453, status=Inprogress , startTime= "2020-04-20 07:07:28"],
        Event[ID=ace-453, status=Inprogress , startTime= "2020-04-20 09:07:28"],
        Event[ID=ace-453, status=Inprogress , startTime= "2020-04-20 07:07:34"] 
        
       ]
```

I am trying to fetch a single record  which is having maximum start time and remove the other object from the list.
The following list is updated on runtime so I want to compare the object and only get the object with maximum time at last.

I tried

```
public List<Event> removeduplicates(List<Event> re){
List<Event> results = new Arraylist<Events>();
results = re;
for(Event e : re){
   if(e.getId() != null && !e.getid().isEmpty() && e.getStatus() == "InProgress"){
     for(Event e1 : results){
        if(e.getId().euqals(e1.getId()) && (e.getStatus().equals(e1.getStatus()))){
           DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
           LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(e.getStarttime(),formatter);
           LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(e1.getStarttime(),formatter);
          if(dt1.isBefore(dt2)){
            result.remove(e);
           }

      }
   }

 }

}
```

but I am getting null list at the end.
also i am not able to use **.remove()** here.

Comment: You are removing elements from the collection you are iterating over, which leads to errors. You could use descending index iteration instead when going over `result`. You are also overwriting `result` with `re`, not making a copy of `re`.

Comment: Unless you've defined a method named `euqals`, it looks like this won't compile.

Comment: Can you share your `Event` class?

Comment: I think you need to iterate through `re` twice. First time to find the maximum `startTime` and second time to extract all elements in the list whose `startTime` matches the maximum.

Comment: @Eritrean This is fine but, the list I am having is updated dynamically so i want to compare object with previous one so that previous object will remove and latest will be added.

Comment: public class Event {
String Id;
String status;



public String  getId(){
return Id;

}

Comment: Are all `id` , `status` and `starttime` Strings?

Comment: @Eritrean    yes it is of strings

Comment: _the list I am having is updated dynamically_ Are you saying that the list is changing while you are iterating over it (apart from the `remove` you are calling)? That would imply that your code is multi-threaded and that another thread is modifying the list while you are iterating over it in method `removeduplicates`. If that is not the case, then in method `removeduplicates` you are working with a list whose contents will not change during the execution of the method. Hence no problem to iterate the list twice.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, your goal is to remove *duplicated events* having the same `id` and `status` and retain only one of them having the latest time.

The issues with your code:

- You're using identity comparison for strings `strings e.getStatus() == "InProgress"` instead of `equals()`.
- It would be much cleaner if `startTime` would be of type `LocalDateTime` and not a `String` in the first place.
- It's not clear do you want to modify the existing list or generate a new one as result of the method execution (because in the code you are creating a new list and then immediately reassigning the variable). In case if you need to modify the existing list, it would more performant not to remove elements one by one, but instead generate a `HashSet` of events that should be retained and then remove all other events in one go using `retainAll()`. It will turn the worst case quadratic time instead into a linear.
- Method name `removeduplicates()` and parameter name `re` are not aligned with [*Java naming conventions*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Assuming that equality of *events* according to the `equals/hashCode` implementation isn't based solely on `id` and `status`. We can generate a map with *keys* created by concatenating `id` and `status`. And then generate a resulting list from based on the values of this map.

The code below generates a *new list*, if you need to modify the one that was passed to a method, then replace `Collectors.toList()` with `Collectors.toSet()` and apply `retainAll()` on the initial list of events.

```
public List<Event> removeDuplicates(List<Event> events) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
    
    return events.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getId() != null && !e.getId().isEmpty() && e.getStatus().equals("InProgress"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> e.getId() + ":" + e.getStatus(),
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(e -> LocalDateTime.parse(e.getStartTime(), formatter)))
        ))
        .values().stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good case where using streams might be very handy instead of a classic for-loop, because the method names will make it obvious what is going on in the method, i.e. grouping by `id + status` and and maping to the object having the max `starttime`. Example: assuming a class `Event` which looks something like :

```
class Event {
    String id;
    String status;
    String startTime;
}
```

And a sample input list:

```
List<Event> result = List.of(
        new Event("ace-453", "Inprogress",  "2020-04-20 07:05:28"),
        new Event("ace-453", "Inprogress",  "2020-04-20 07:07:28"),
        new Event("ace-453", "Inprogress",  "2020-04-20 09:07:28"),
        new Event("ace-453", "Inprogress",  "2020-04-20 07:07:34")
);
```

then your method could look like

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


....


public List<Event> removeduplicates(List<Event> result){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return new ArrayList<>(
            result.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            event -> event.getId() + event.getStatus(),
                            Function.identity(),
                            BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                                    Comparator.comparing(event -> LocalDateTime.parse(event.getStartTime(),formatter)))))
                    .values());
}
```